# How can I be sure I wrote a full model including all the possible random effect terms in lmer in R?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have an experiment amenable of being analyzed using mixed models. This is a mock up example. I have two field locations. Within each field there are two blocks, called block 1 and 2. Since the locations are geographically separated, blocks are nested in the locations. Then, I tested two groups of plants; let's say type tall and type short. Within each plant type I have two random cultivars representing these plant types. Since a particular cultivar cannot be type tall and short (either you are a short type plant or a tall type plant), I am assuming cultivars are nested within plant type. Finally, I have a treatment of irrigation or no irrigation applied to all the plots.

So, for my model, the fixed terms would be type and treatment. All other factors and interactions are random effects.

The specific question I have is how can I be sure that I am including all the random effects interactions to have an initial full model? What I tried to do is to write all the interactions with the intent of having a zero residual.

This is my reproducible example:

```
data.1 <-read.csv(text = "
location,block,type,cultivar,trat,response
loc_a,1,short,cult_C,irrigated,15.9
loc_a,1,short,cult_C,no_irrigated,10.4
loc_a,1,short,cult_D,irrigated,18.2
loc_a,1,short,cult_D,no_irrigated,12
loc_a,1,tall,cult_A,irrigated,14.8
loc_a,1,tall,cult_A,no_irrigated,10.2
loc_a,1,tall,cult_B,irrigated,16.8
loc_a,1,tall,cult_B,no_irrigated,12.2
loc_a,2,short,cult_C,irrigated,16.5
loc_a,2,short,cult_C,no_irrigated,12.8
loc_a,2,short,cult_D,irrigated,15.2
loc_a,2,short,cult_D,no_irrigated,11.7
loc_a,2,tall,cult_A,irrigated,14
loc_a,2,tall,cult_A,no_irrigated,12
loc_a,2,tall,cult_B,irrigated,13.9
loc_a,2,tall,cult_B,no_irrigated,8.8
loc_b,1,short,cult_C,irrigated,15
loc_b,1,short,cult_C,no_irrigated,16.3
loc_b,1,short,cult_D,irrigated,21.9
loc_b,1,short,cult_D,no_irrigated,14.3
loc_b,1,tall,cult_A,irrigated,19.1
loc_b,1,tall,cult_A,no_irrigated,13
loc_b,1,tall,cult_B,irrigated,22.3
loc_b,1,tall,cult_B,no_irrigated,13.7
loc_b,2,short,cult_C,irrigated,21.9
loc_b,2,short,cult_C,no_irrigated,20.9
loc_b,2,short,cult_D,irrigated,21
loc_b,2,short,cult_D,no_irrigated,19.6
loc_b,2,tall,cult_A,irrigated,21.5
loc_b,2,tall,cult_A,no_irrigated,17.3
loc_b,2,tall,cult_B,irrigated,17.8
loc_b,2,tall,cult_B,no_irrigated,13.8
")

library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

model.1 <-lmer(response ~ type * trat  
             + (1 | location/block)         # location and block nested in location
             + (1 | type:location)          # type by location
             + (1 | type:block:location)    # type by block nested in location
             + (1 | cultivar:type)            # cultivar nested in type
             + (1 | cultivar:type:location)   # cultivar nested in type by location
             + (1 | cultivar:type:block:location) #cultivar nested in type by block nested in location
             + (1 | trat:location)          # trat by location
             + (1 | trat:block:location)    # trat by block nested in location
             + (1 | trat:type:location)     # trat by type by location
             + (1 | trat:type:block:location) # trat by type by block nested in location
             + (1 | trat:cultivar:type)       # trat by cultivar nested in type
             + (1 | trat:cultivar:type:location) # trat by cultivar nested in type by location
             + (1 | trat:cultivar:type:block:location) # trat by cultivar nested in type by location
             ,data=data.1)
```

when I run this i got the following error:

```
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations
```

When I run the model again without the last random term `(1 | trat:cultivar:type:block:location)`  the model runs well.

In summary, I have three questions. First, are the random terms structure and sintax adecuate for the experimental design I described above? Second, am I getting the error I mentioned because the model need this term to calculate a residual term. Third, the model without this term `(1 | trat:cultivar:type:block:location)`   can be considered a full model including all the interactions and the residual term is actually this last term of my model?

Comment: If you have only two locations and two blocks on each of these, that's simply not enough to estimate random effects. Also, a variable cannot simultaneously be a fixed effect and the grouping variable of a random effect. In such a case, it should be a random slope. Anyway, I'd say you don't have enough replicates on the nesting levels to fit random effects. You should switch to a fixed effects model. (I sometimes model four blocks as a random effect and some experts would already challenge that. Common advice is that you should have about 30 subjects in a random effect.)

Comment: @Roland, thanks so much for the response. I fully agree on what you said about the amount of data. The real dataset has about 20 locations and way more types and cultivars. That's why I was inclined for this analysis. You comment about "a variable cannot simultaneously be a fixed effect and the grouping variable of a random effect" intrigues me.  That means that adding this ```(1 | type:location)``` in the random term is plain wrong? Ask you can deduce, my understanding of these models is quite rudimentary, so I apology beforehand if this is a too basic question. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Your "full" model should probably be something like `response ~ type * trat + (type * trat | location/block)`. I'm not sure if and how the cultivars are subject to repeated measures. These might be a crossed random effect but I can't tell from the information provided (I didn't look at the data in detail).